# ¿Por qué al guardar archivo .js en vscode me envía a la parte final del código?

Tags: javascript, vscode, formato, extensiones

Estoy trabajando con javascript sobre la plantilla  AdminLTE. recién cambié de equipo y reinstalé vscode mudando las extensiones y configuraciones mediante "settings Sync", todo bien hasta que me empezó a dar lata que cuando guardo (o al guardar en automático) un js me manda directo al fin de mi código en ese archivo, no tengo problema cuando son archivos de pocas líneas porque rápido puedo volver a la(s) línea(s) donde me encontraba editando pero en documentos de miles de líneas ya empieza a molestar

¿Alguien que se le ocurra algo o le haya pasado algo similar?

Como dato extra, las extensiones que tengo instaladas son:

- Docker
- ESLint
- Format HTML in PHP
- IntelliSense for CSS  class names in HTML
- JavaScript (ES6) code snippets
- Material Icon Theme
- Path Intellisense
- PHP debug
- PHP Intelliphense
- Prettier - Code formatter
- WSL